# How to use async await in React using the axios in the API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux

I am new to the web development. I am using `react.js`.So, Here I want to use the `async/await`for the API call. I am using `axios`.

Now,

what I have is like

```
export function fetchToken(bodyjson) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    let url = LOGIN_PATH + "username=" + bodyjson.userName + "&password" + "=" + bodyjson.password;
    return post(url, bodyjson)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          localStorage.setItem('user', bodyjson.userName);
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.payload.access_token);
          history.push('/');
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            data: response.payload,
          })
        }
        else {
          dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAILED,
            data: response.status,
          });
        }
      })
  }
}
```

and my post service is like,

```
export const post = (url, post_data) =>
    axios.post(
        apiGatewayEndpoint.apiGatewayEndpoint + url,
        post_data,
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("access_token") !== null ? `Bearer ` + localStorage.getItem("access_token") : null,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    ).then(data => {
        if (data.status === HttpStatus.OK) {
            return {
                status: data.status,
                payload: data.data
            };
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return {
            status: err.response.data,
            payload: null
        };
    });
```

Now, I want to use the async await over here. I am very confused between this. I have gone through lots of the tutorials. 
 I want to call an API immediately after the `login`. on that basis I want to redirect user to the diff pages.

So, can any one help me with this `async-await`

THANKS:-)

Now I am using it like,

```
export function fetchToken(bodyjson) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    let url = LOGIN_PATH + "username=" + bodyjson.userName + "&password" + "=" + bodyjson.password;
    let response = await post(url, bodyjson)
    if (response.status === 200) {
      localStorage.setItem('user', bodyjson.userName);
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.payload.access_token);
      let fetchJd = FETCH_JD_ROOT_URL + page + "&" + size;
      let newApiResponse = await get(fetchJd)
      if (newApiResponse.status === 200) {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
          data: response.payload,
        })
        dispatch(sendUserJd(newApiResponse.payload));
      }else {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAILED,
      data: response.status,
    });
  }

    }
    else {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAILED,
        data: response.status,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you just want to convert promises to use `async/await`, perhaps you will find this post helpful? https://sylvainleroy.com/2017/12/21/away-async-vs-promises/

Answer (score 2):

for get requests, you can use params to send data etc etc.

```
   export const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios({
            method: 'get', //you can set what request you want to be
            url: `yoururl`,
            params: {
            // key values pairs   
            }
            headers: {
                'token': token
            }
        });
        // run some validation before returning
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return .. some error object;
    }
};
```

for post request

```
export const getData = async (params) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios({
            method: 'post', //you can set what request you want to be
            url: `url`,
            data: params,
            headers: {
                'x-auth-Token': token
            }
        });
        // run some validation before returning
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return .. some error object;
    }
};
```

error object example

```
{
  status: 'error',
  message: 'failed with something'
}
```

then you can call any api like this,

```
async componentDidMount() {
 const data = await getData();
 if(data.status === 'Something') {
// do something    
  }
}
```

Comment: So, I should replace the post call with this ?

Comment: I want to call an api immediately after the login success

Comment: yeah you can do it, if you want to call after login... and i hope when you do all your calls in async await, you just need to call login api first, like await login(), then call other api like await getSomething() and so on. makes your api's reusable and readable

Answer (score 1):

You dont exactly need async await for this purpose.

With **then chain** approach

```
export function fetchToken(bodyjson) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        let url = LOGIN_PATH + "username=" + bodyjson.userName + "&password" + "=" + bodyjson.password;
        return post(url, bodyjson)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('user', bodyjson.userName);
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.payload.access_token);
                history.push('/');
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                    data: response.payload,
                })
                //next api call
                return post(newUrl, newBodyjson)
            }
            else {
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_FAILED,
                    data: response.status,
                });
            }
        })
        .then((newApiResponse) => {
            //Do stuffs with new api response
        })
    }
}
```

But if you want to use **async-await** approach only

```
export function fetchToken(bodyjson) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        let url = LOGIN_PATH + "username=" + bodyjson.userName + "&password" + "=" + bodyjson.password;
        let response = await post(url, bodyjson)
        if (response.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('user', bodyjson.userName);
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.payload.access_token);
                history.push('/');
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                    data: response.payload,
                })
                let newApiResponse = await post(newUrl, newBodyjson)
                //Do stuffs with new api response
            }
            else {
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_FAILED,
                    data: response.status,
                });
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add one catch block at the end of all .then, and handle errors there

Comment: Hey,  I have used your way. here what is happening is when I click on login that time it gives response and I dispatch that so because of that it changes props immediately but till that time the second request has not yet given response. So, How should I handle this, that before dispatching the response of first request, Should I send the response of this two requests in the newapi call itself?>

Comment: depending on your need you change where you want to dispatch. As per issue I think you should dispatch in the new api then block i.e. after making new call

Comment: I am sorry I asking you one more question. Now, I am totally new so , Now if first api call is success but the second api call gets failed, and In that api call only  I am redirecting user to some another page so, In this case what should I do ? and I have used async await  I have updated in the question  please take a look

Comment: should I handle the errors in the else part of that request ?

Comment: for over all errors you can wrap the await thing in try catch. If you are asking about how to handle stuff based on response of second api call you can simply use if else base on `newApiResponse`

Comment: from what i can understand just dispatch `dispatch({
                    type: LOGIN_FAILED,
                    data: response.status,
                });` if `newApiResponse` is invalid or failed.

Comment: so Here I have used your solution. I will just update the solution In my question If you think I have used in the right way please let me know.